# How can start working with lawyers in need? NOT ADVERTISEMENT

Tags: software, employment, non-profit

I'm genuinely trying to understand where I could help the most and what problems my skills could be applied to that lawyers are fighting with on the daily. This is my first question on here and if it's in the wrong location please assist me in the right direction.

I'm interested in providing my Machine Learning & Automation skills to a law firm in need. I was watching a story from Vice (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqLE4ryWMX4&ab_channel=VICENews) and saw how much the Public Defenders are buried in their caseload. While this video is in Missouri I'd be more interested in working with local firms (Texas).

Watching this video I quickly see a problem that I've solved with other clients. Like building a pipeline that digitizes/highspeed-scanning cases, indexing them for search-as-you-type queries, and using Machine Learning to both strategize and extract patterns.

My question is, how would I get my foot in the door? I'd be willing to volunteer if need be, but I would ultimately like to turn a profit once a clear ROI is established. Would a Public Defender be a good choice to help? I'd like to help someone who could really use my skills and not so much looking for a Whale Firm. The main goal would be to automize as much as possible via the use of client web services, apps, and desktop applications, as I am capable of building everything. This would be in the hopes of freeing up a firm's time & human resources.

Comment: Your question isn't likely to receive useful answers because it appears to be thinly disguised advertising.  (I upvoted it, and then thought better of it.)

Comment: Try calling the Texas Bar.

Comment: @WHO'sNoToOldRx4CovidIsMurder No. This would be a very stupid place to advertise. That's why I stated my local area. In hopes that people would take the hint that this is for my local community. But I will edit it.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I might do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to just find some lawyers and pick their brains. This isn't easy; every professional (whatever their field) has to have defences against the snake-oil merchants, and there isn't an easy way through them. Your best bet is probably personal connections; do you know anyone who might know some lawyers, and can give you an introduction?

You have a solution and you are looking for a problem. This is the wrong way around; you need to concentrate on figuring out the problems, and then see if you can help to solve any of them.

When you do get to talk to a lawyer, ask about the pain points in their work; what stuff soaks up valuable time in seemingly wasteful ways? Don't talk about your solutions; you need to LISTEN above all. Talk to as many as you can, then take a long hard look at the answers. Anything common turning up?

The legal system also has "paralegals"; people who are not legally qualified but have enough knowledge of the law to assist lawyers with routine stuff like drafting documents. You might try talking to them about what parts of their job might benefit from automation and AI. They also might be easier to get hold of; because they don't have decision authority the snake-oil merchants are less keen to pitch to them.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your solutions may not be what the user actually needs

1. You have proposed solutions that have not involved the users.  This is poor use-case design.
2. Your hurdle will be convincing people who have high workloads that your solutions might help them.
3. No one is going to let some rando off the street into their case files.
4. You are using people's time to create a profit-driven product.  Who would do this for you?
5. I suggest that the issues that keep public defenders busy are court time, meetings with clients, meeting with prosecutors, and drafting documents.  Digitizing cases with keywords would be a very minor improvement; most documents are already digitized.